# How is Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15 able to mutate Synthetics?

Tags: comics, robots, alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator

The *Alien* prequels reveal that aeons ago, life on Earth came into through the machinations of an ancient alien race dubbed the Mala'kaks/Engineers. The Mala'kaks/Engineers accomplished this feat through a potent mutagen called Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15 composed of nanoparticles that induce mutations in living organisms exposed to the substance by "operating off on an algorithm based on evolutionary computing".

In the *Alien vs Predator: Fire and Stone* comic books, which occur eighty-eight years after the events of *Prometheus* and *Alien: Covenant*, a Synthetic, by the name of Elden, get a sample of Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15. This event occurs when a scientist theories that it could possess curative properties once filtered through a Synthetic's techno-organic systems. But, Elden only ends up mutating into a rage-filled abomination who becomes progressively more monstrous as the story goes on.

I've been puzzled about how Chemical A0-3959X.91 – 15 could affect Synthetics when it has shown only to mutate organic creatures.

How could such phenomena get explained or justified?

Comment: Just a theory, hence only a comment, could it be that the synthetics also have some organic components?